# Julia convert symbol to string

Tags: string, type-conversion, julia, symbols

How do I convert a symbol to a string in Julia?  The following don't work:

```
String(:A)
convert(String,:A)
```

They did work in Julia version 0.4.

Answer (score 10):

You could use the `string` function:

```
julia> string(:A)
"A"
```

However as of Julia 1.5.1 `String(symb)` also seems to work:

```
julia> String(:A)
"A"
```

However `String(:A)` is the recommended method as it just directly creates the `String` object from `Symbol` and hence is 3x faster.